# Display more than one image in DataGridView Image Column? Is it possible?

Tags: datagridview

Is it possible to display more than one image in a column in DataGridViewImageColumn? I have only 1 column and need to dynamically display images. This column could display 1 to 3 images, depending on other conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could draw the two images you want to display onto a third, new image and then display that in the column.

Something like this:

```
        Bitmap Image1 = new Bitmap(10, 10); //replace with your first image
        Bitmap Image2 = new Bitmap(10, 10); //replace with your second image
        Bitmap ImageToDisplayInColumn = new Bitmap(Image1.Width + Image2.Width, Image1.Height);
        using (Graphics graphicsObject = Graphics.FromImage(ImageToDisplayInColumn))
        {
            graphicsObject.DrawImage(Image1, new Point(0, 0));
            graphicsObject.DrawImage(Image2, new Point(Image1.Width, 0));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several articles around on creating custom DataGridViewColumns. Here's one from [CODE magazine](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0707061). It sounds like you want to write your own code to paint the column with the appropriate image or images.